# AWS resource creation failed due to account currently being verified

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I try to create EC2 servers in a fresh AWS account, I get the below error message. I was successfully able to create an S3 bucket, however, I faced below when I try to launch EC2 servers from a CFT.

> Your account is currently being verified. Verification normally takes
>   less than 2 hours. Until your account is verified, you may not be able
>   to launch additional instances or create additional volumes. If you
>   are still receiving this message after more than 2 hours, please let
>   us know by writing to aws-verification@amazon.com. We appreciate your
>   patience. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   PendingVerification; Request ID: )

This account is one of the child account from AWS Organizations, and I never faced this issue in other ones.

Any idea why this caused?

Comment: It is an AWS anti-fraud measure. Please follow the advise given by the message you have quoted.

Comment: Yeah, it went away in a couple of hours. Just wanted to know why it caused all randomly. Thanks, John